# Longpress simulation with onmousedown but also has onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML

```
<li onclick="setServerID(this);" class="server-item-item" data-server="1" onmousedown="serverHold(this);" onmouseup="serverRelease();"><span>MyServer</span></li>
```

My JS looks like:

```
function setServerID(server) {
    sessionStorage.serverID = server.dataset.server;
    getServerInfo();
    gotoMain();
}
```

And

```
function serverHold(server) {
    pressTimer = window.setTimeout(function() {
        var id = server.dataset.server;
        clearTimeout(pressTimer);
        $('#fav-the-server').css("visibility", "visible");
        a.slide('fav-the-server', "left", 0, "200ms", "ease", "0ms", "1", "alternate", "running");

    },1000);
    return false;
}
```

This all works fantastically thanks to previous posts I looked up on SO but the issue is that its a touchscreen type app and it executes the `onclick`

Anyway to do this that lets me get the following functionality:

> List Item -> Click and Hold for 1000ms -> Execute `serverHold` and do
>   not execute the `setServerID`

AND

> List Item -> Click and do not hold or hold for less than 1000ms - >
>   Execute `setServerID` only.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep a flag indicating if you have processed a long press during the click: [demo](http://jsbin.com/oxuwux/2/edit)